# How can I resolve "Recv failure: Connection reset by peer" error

Tags: git, fatal-error, git-pull, git-fetch

I'm trying `$ git pull`  or `$ git fetch` command on `myRepo` gives me error but `myTestRepo` works fine.

Commands give me that error.

```
Fetching origin
fatal: unable to access 'http://mysite/myPath/myRepo.git/': Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
error: Could not fetch origin
```

I tried git `$ git fetch -p` and `$ git fetch -p --all -f` command, they worked one or two times after that that commands give the same error.

Comment: Are you able to otherwise access the git repo ? Maybe in a browser ?

Comment: yes I can reach my repo with browser, and I can push my changes on the repo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was using `http` connection, I changed my connection to `ssh` instead of http and the problem was solved

Answer (score 4):

I encounter similar problem but figure it out. Actually, there is no `http` but `https` for github. Try to replace `http` to `https`.

Answer (score 1):

If your company uses *github* through a ***proxy*** then:

In your user **.gitconfig** file, include the proxy URL that corresponds to HTTPS.

Like the following example:

```
[https]
    proxy = https://YOUR_HTTPS_PROXY:PORT_NUMBER
```

or just run

```
git config --global https.https://domain.com.proxy https://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port
```

You can see more here:

https://gist.github.com/evantoli/f8c23a37eb3558ab8765

Answer (score 1):

For problems syncing **GitHub**:

1. In IntelliJ press `Ctrl+Alt+S` and go to `GitHub` section (not `Git`).
2. Check the `Clone git repositories using ssh` checkbox.
3. Update project.

Answer (score 0):

It could happen if 80 is blocked when you are using http url.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem with

```
git clone xyz.git
```

I solve it adding the sudo commando

```
sudo git clone xyz.git
```

Comment: In most cases, unless you are doing something very unusual, you do not use `sudo` to clone repositories.