# Recv failure: Connection was reset

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I got this error when I ran `git push -u origin main` in Git Bash:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Khadija-Emran/BenEmran.git/': Recv failure: Connection was reset

[image: error]

I tried to access GitHub from another browser and I checked my internet connection also.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58372156/how-can-i-resolve-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer-error